# If I change the entity after getting it from database in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using hibernate and  JPA repository for CRUD operations. I am getting all the records by findAll method and I want to remove some non-public field of the entity.

I am new in Hibernate and confused a little bit. In my entity object, I have list of object. So basically:

```
public MyClass{
    private List<MyObject> myList;
    ....
}
```

I am getting all MyClass object from database and I need to remove some elements from the myList before returning it to the client. So my question is If I remove it, Hibernate will automatically detect and update the db or not ? Because I do not want to update DB. The reason is only to hide from user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not fetching data withing transaction, nothing will be saved to the database.

If you're within a transaction, you can detach the entity by using `EntityManager#detach`. There will be no dirty tracking then and nothing will be saved to the database.